# how to copy data from variable list of parquet files using pyspark

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, databricks, parquet

I have saved the list of parquet files(to be read) in a variable list, say listOffilteredFiles()

Now I want to read all the files from this list and write all the data into a single parquet file in another path. How can I do this. I have written the below code and I'm stuck here. Any help would be appreciated

```
   import time
   import datetime
   from datetime import datetime
   import pandas as pd
   import glob
   import pyspark
   from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

   dirName = 'dbfs:/mnt/abc/def/efg'
   now = datetime.utcnow()
   
   # Get the list of all files in directory tree at given path
   listOfFiles = list()
   listOffilteredFiles = list()
   
   for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dirName):
       listOfFiles += [os.path.join(dirpath, file) for file in filenames]        

   listOffilteredFiles = filter(lambda x: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(x)) < now, listOfFiles)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the files you're trying to read are parquet files.
You can read all the parquet files from a directory using * syntax.
Suppose you have a directory like this:

```
/abc/def/[file1.parquet, file2.parquet, file3.parquet]
/abc/ghi/[file1.parquet, file2.parquet, file3.parquet]
```

and you wanna read all the parquet files under `/abc` directory. The spark read statement would be:

```
df = spark.read.parquet('/abc/*/*')
```

In another scenario, when you need to read some files after filtering them, you can do:

```
listOffilteredFiles = list(filter(lambda x: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(x)) < now, listOfFiles))

df = spark.read.parquet(*listOffilteredFiles)
```

Comment: My requirement is I have to read files which have come after last job run date, so I have to filter out files based on their last modified date. This is how I am filtering the list of files.      ```for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dirName):
       listOfFiles += [os.path.join(dirpath, file) for file in filenames]        

   listOffilteredFiles = filter(lambda x: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(x)) < now, listOfFiles) ```   Is there a way to put filter condition in the command you've provided.

Comment: Yes sorry I missed the last part of your code. I have edited my response.

Comment: Thanks @ARCrow for the quick response. I have tried this too, but got some error.   

``` listOffilteredFiles = filter(lambda x: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(x)) < now, listOfFiles)                                

    df = spark.read.parquet(*listOffilteredFiles)    

    Error:  analysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.``` I might be missing something. Please help

Comment: This error happens when you're reading directories which contain subdirectories rather than parquet files. Print out the output of the filter and make sure the directories you're trying to read are correct. Or use ```*``` syntax to read all the content of subdirectories.

Comment: listOffilteredFiles is not a directory, its a list of parquet file paths. Example :  listOffilteredFiles = [/mnt/a/b/a.parquet, /mnt/a/d/c.parquet, /mnt/a/c/d.parquet]